# Output of Clojure Compiler in SBT Project

Tags: clojure, compilation, sbt, playframework-2.0, clojure-java-interop

tl;dr: Unexpected layout of `.class` files produced by clojure compiler invoked from scala code.

I have an SBT project (using playframework) that includes some clojure code. The clojure compiler is being called from [an SBT task](https://gist.github.com/thomasmatecki/2458a5f44d88191415c846d94393b884) in the `build.sbt` file. [Here](https://gist.github.com/thomasmatecki/d338cc02181b433dd3a740270dfa161d) is the scala code invoking the clojure compiler(credit to: [sbt-clojure](https://github.com/Geal/sbt-clojure)).

The compiler is outputting `.class` files, **but** not in the layout I expect( based on the `ns` definition).

If I define my clojure namespace as follows:

```
(ns api.datastore.foo
  (:require [clojure.core.async :refer (<!!)]
            [datomic.client :as client])

  (:gen-class
    :methods [#^{:static true} [bar [java.util.List] clojure.lang.ISeq]])
```

... and this clojure source is located in `app/api/datastore`, then the layout of files resulting from clojure compilation is this:

```
└── classes
    ├── foo__init.class
    └── api
        └── datastore
            ├── foo.class
            ├── foo$fn__3.class
            ├── foo$loading__5569__auto____1.class
            └── foo$_bar.class
```

When I try to call any of this code (e.g. function `bar`), an error results:

...`java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate api/datastore/foo__init.class or api/datastore/foo.clj on classpath`...

Changing the definition of my namespace (note `:name` key) to this:

```
(ns foo
  (:require [clojure.core.async :refer (<!!)]
            [datomic.client :as client])

  (:gen-class
    :name api.datastore.foo
    :methods [#^{:static true} [bar [java.util.List] clojure.lang.ISeq]])
```

... and moving this clojure source to `app/` produces output like this:

```
└── classes
    ├── foo__init.class
    ├── foo$fn__3.class
    ├── foo$loading__5569__auto____1.class
    ├── foo$_bar.class
    └── api
        └── datastore
            └── foo.class
```

... and it works!

**But**, now I don't have any directory structure for my clojure sources(the all have to be in `app/`), **which is a problem** for a number of reasons. Is there anyway to do this without the `:name` key(i.e. get the target directory structure that works from the namespace definition that doesn't)?